# Create Nested Object from Flat Object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of Object like

```
  [
      {
        "parentId": "uniqueParentId1",
        "parentName": "Parent1",
        "childProp1": "test1",
        "childProp2": "test3"
      },
      {
        "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
        "parentName": "Parent2",
        "childProp1": "somevals",
        "childProp2": "other vals"
      }
      {
        "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
        "parentName": "Parent2",
        "childProp1": "somevals 1",
        "childProp2": "other vals 1"
      }
    ]
```

and I want to combine it based in parentId and create an array of Object like below in Javascript . How can I do it ?

```
    [
      {
        "id": "uniqueParentId1",
        "name": "Parent1",
        "children": [
          {
            "childProp1": "test1",
            "childProp2": "test3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "uniqueParentId2",
        "name": "Parent2",
        "children": [
          {
            "childProp1": "somevals",
            "childProp2": "other vals"
          },
          {
            "childProp1": "somevals 1",
            "childProp2": "other vals 1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

The idea to convert flat object to nested Object is so that I can use the nested Object in Iterations easiely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with javascript easily. Create and make new array according to your old array.

```
var oldArray = [
    {
        "parentId": "uniqueParentId1",
        "parentName": "Parent1",
        "childProp1": "test1",
        "childProp2": "test3"
    },
    {
        "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
        "parentName": "Parent2",
        "childProp1": "somevals",
        "childProp2": "other vals"
    },
    {
        "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
        "parentName": "Parent2",
        "childProp1": "somevals 1",
        "childProp2": "other vals 1"
    }
];

var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    var currentObject = newArray.filter(function (x) { return x.id == 
oldArray[i].parentId })[0];
    if (currentObject == null) {
        var newObj = {
            id: oldArray[i].parentId,
            name: oldArray[i].parentName,
            children: [
                {
                    childProp1: oldArray[i].childProp1,
                    childProp2: oldArray[i].childProp2
                }
            ]
        };
        newArray.push(newObj)
    }
    else {
        currentObject.children.push({
            childProp1: oldArray[i].childProp1,
            childProp2: oldArray[i].childProp2
        });
    }
}
console.log(newArray); // your array is here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: loop through your array and create a new array with the data you need, i didn't know what the name variable was supposed to be so i generated it.. if that is supposed to be the parentId number you can extract the digits from `o.parentId`
I've also assumed that except parentId all other object keys are childs...

```js
let arr = [{
    "parentId": "uniqueParentId1",
    "childProp1": "test1",
    "childProp2": "test3"
  },
  {
    "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
    "childProp1": "somevals",
    "childProp2": "other vals"
  },
  {
    "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
    "childProp1": "somevals 1",
    "childProp2": "other vals 1"
  }
];


let combined = {};
let parentid = 1;
let childs = {};
arr.map(o => {
  if (!combined[o.parentId]) {
    combined[o.parentId] = {
      id: o.parentId,
      name: "Parent" + parentid,
      children: []
    };
    parentid++;
  }
  childs = {}
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(o)) {
    if (key !== 'parentId') childs[key] = value;
  }
  combined[o.parentId].children.push(childs);
});
console.log(combined)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const flatObjects = [{parentId: 'uniqueParentId1',parentName: 'Parent1',childProp1: 'test1',childProp2: 'test3',},{parentId: 'uniqueParentId2',parentName: 'Parent2',childProp1: 'somevals',childProp2: 'other vals',},{parentId: 'uniqueParentId2',parentName: 'Parent2',childProp1: 'somevals 1',childProp2: 'other vals 1'}]

const result = Object.values(
  flatObjects.reduce((a, c) => {
    const k = `${c.parentId}|${c.parentName}`
    a[k] = a[k] || {
      id: c.parentId,
      name: c.parentName,
      children: [],
    }
    a[k].children.push({
      childProp1: c.childProp1,
      childProp2: c.childProp2,
    })
    return a
  }, {})
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map data structure to store childrens of same parent, then conevert the map into Array.

```js
const array = [{
        "parentId": "uniqueParentId1",
        "parentName": "Parent1",
        "childProp1": "test1",
        "childProp2": "test3"
    },
    {
        "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
        "parentName": "Parent2",
        "childProp1": "somevals",
        "childProp2": "other vals"
    },
    {
        "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
        "parentName": "Parent2",
        "childProp1": "somevals 1",
        "childProp2": "other vals 1"
    }
]
let map = new Map();
array.forEach((item) => {
    if (map.has(item.parentId)) {
        map.get(item.parentId).children.push({
            "childProp1": item.childProp1,
            "childProp2": item.childProp2
        })
    } else {
        map.set(item.parentId, {
            "id": item.parentId,
            "name": item.parentName,
            children: [{
                "childProp1": item.childProp1,
                "childProp2": item.childProp2
            }]
        })
    }
})
let result = [];
map.forEach((value)=>{
  result.push(value)
})
console.log(result)
```